# How to host a custom webdav module in IIS?

Tags: iis, webdav

I have been using an open source WebDAV framework named "Sphorium" for quite some time to talk to my data repository.. I have been using Cassini web server to host my WebDAV server module and everything was working just fine if I map the server as a web folder in my system. However, i found that Cassini web server does not support "https". So, I started looking out for deploying my WebDAV server application in IIS.. So I built a website in ASP .Net which talks to the Sphorium WebDAV module and authorizes the user. And when I run my website using the VS Debugger, it gets hosted on the ASP .Net development web server, prompts for the credentials and works just fine. However, if I publish my web app and try to host in in IIS, and try to browse, it prompts me for the password for 3 times and finally says "Unauthorized"...

Could someone pls throw some light on how I can use IIS in this case? Do I have to give any permissions?